# How NN processes a pattern\ dataset formed of millions of points as a single input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I would like to know how NN processes a pattern\ dataset formed of millions of points as a single input. Does NN cluster the dataset and or extract the features? How does Sigmoid transfer function convert these points to a single number (from o to 1) in the first hidden layer?

Answer (score 0):

The sigmoid function is 1/(1+e^(x*w)), where x is your vector of inputs and w is your vector of weights. After you multiply the elements of w and x you sum their products (this is called a "linear combination"), and this results in a single scalar value. Feeding this scalar into the sigmoid returns, not surprisingly, a transformed scalar but still a scalar nonetheless.

The key is understanding what a linear combination is. It's nothing more than linear regression  or how any linear combination/equation works (e.g., y = mx + b).